# How to disable the in-app update notification on Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos

When opening [Google Photos](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.photos) and if there is a newer version, it says that I need to upgrade. You can of course click no, but it is very troublesome to do it always.

Is there any way to disable this popup without upgrading the app?

I got a rooted device.

Comment: Related: [Any way to disable "update now" popup upon opening Google Photos App?](https://support.google.com/photos/thread/172715786/any-way-to-disable-update-now-popup-upon-opening-google-photos-app)

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the Android Settings
2. Find the Google Photos app
3. Disable background data

Answer (score 0):

When you get the notification next time, long press it and you will get the Settings or the details option based on the version of Android running on your device. Once you select the option, you will be taken to the notification settings page of the app and from there you can choose to turn off the notification for that particular popup category or for the entire app.

Comment: Apparently this is a pop-up notification inside the app, not an Android system notification. AFAIK, it can't be disabled from any settings. (ref: [Any way to disable "update now" popup upon opening Google Photos App?](https://support.google.com/photos/thread/172715786/any-way-to-disable-update-now-popup-upon-opening-google-photos-app))

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I have a solution, more of a workaround and not the best one, but it works for me, I used MacroDroid to dismiss that window automatically. I'm using Photos v5.52.

Application Launched (Photos) > Wait 750 ms, Repeat 7 times{Click[com.google.android.apps.photos:id/negative_button], Wait 100 ms}

It's the UI interaction action and identify in app function.

Didn't find any other solution.. tried LuckyPatcher to change some components, detaching from store, XprivacyLua, but no luck.

Macro here: http://bit.ly/3HAHwBc